# Usar oracle Entity Data Model C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, visual-studio-2017

Tengo una base de datos en Oracle, quiero agregar un *Entity Data Model* en mi proyecto C#, pero no puedo agregar una nueva conexión ya que solo tengo origen de datos SQL Server y al darle clic en "cambiar" no aparece Oracle, sino solo SQL Server. ¿Qué me esta faltando configurar para poder conectarme a Oracle?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por defecto tienes solo el de sql server, ¿has instalado el proveedor de datos para oracles? En los paquetes de nugget  busca oracle.EntityFramework

Comment: Te pido que no dupliques preguntas y más si no tienen toda la información entre ellas